Make column elements display across row instead of column
I currently have the following grid setup to display some images (see image below):
<div class="columns-2 md:columns-5 flex-row">
    {#each image_url_set as img_url}
        <CldImage src={img_url} alt="<Description>" class="w-full pb-3 " />
    {/each}
</div>

https://i.sstatic.net/FBuOKYVo.png
However, the images are ordered in the list they come from, and are ordered down the columns. How can I get them to order across the rows instead, while still maintaining the display of the columns?

We do not accept image links that are not done through the officlal SO imgur account, so that the image remains valid for future site users. Please [edit] your post and use the Add Image toolbar button instead.

You're after a masonry layout. The only way to do that with CSS only is as you have done it now. To keep the masonry layout but have it go across, you'd need to look at using JavaScript to manually position the elements how you want.
